# R unexpected comma with manipulate

Tags: r

I am getting an error with the manipulate function below:

```
 manipulate
 ({
    x<-mat.or.vec(n)
    plot(x)},n = slider(1, 10, initial = 1, step = 1))
```

The error is :

```
 Error: unexpected ',' in:
  "   x<-mat.or.vec(n)
    plot(x)},"
```

Any ideas what the syntax should be? Thank you.

Comment: Well for one, you should bring the open paren up to the same line as the function name.  Otherwise you'll print the source code.  When I bring the two together, it errors with `Error in mat.or.vec(n) : argument "nc" is missing, with no default`.  Not sure where that's coming from but problem 1 solved

Comment: If you want further help you should start you code section with `library(name_of_pkg)`